# To implement registration page with Vaadin or not?

Tags: vaadin

This is a tactical implementation question about usage of Vaadin or in some part of my application.

Vaadin is a great framework to login users and implement sophisticated web applications with many pages. However, I think it is not very well suited to desgin pages to register new users for my application. Am I right? Am I am wrong?

It seems to me that a simple HTML/CSS/Javascript login + email registration + confirmation email with confirmation link cannot be implemented easily with Vaadin. It seems like Vaadin would be overkill. Do you agree? Or am I missing something?

I am looking for feedback from experienced Vaadin users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to make the same decision and went for a simple HTML login using plain servlets and templates. The rationale was:

1) We're using OpenID and I experienced some difficulty catching redirects from providers in a Vaadin app.

2) By managing security at the servlet level there is a reduced surface area for attack. You can just override getNewApplication in AbstractApplicationServlet to control access to the app.  This approach is recommended in this article: [Creating Secure Vaadin Applications using JEE6](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating%20Secure%20Vaadin%20Applications%20using%20JEE6#section-Creating+Secure+Vaadin+Applications+using+JEE6-SecuringTheWebLayer)

Answer (score 3):

Login/registration can be implemented with Vaadin, but there are good arguments to implement login page as a JSP too. It is often question on if you have a traditional web site too and how you want to integrate to that.

Comment: OK. Are these arguments purely functional or are they technical too? If they are technical, what are these?